# Why ngKeydown does not respond sometime?

Tags: angularjs

All:

What I want to do is add a key listener to control a menu toggle on the page.

```
<body ng-controller="main" ng-keydown="toggleSideBar($event)">
```

In main controller:

```
$scope.sidebarOpen = false;
$scope.toggleSideBar = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 18){ // 'ALT' key
        $scope.sidebarOpen = !$scope.sidebarOpen;
    }
}
```

In the template:

```
.sidebar {
    left:100px; 
    transition: left 0.5s;
}
.sidebar.open {
    left:0px; 
    transition: left 0.5s;
}
<div class="sidebar" ng-class="{'open': sidebarOpen}">
```

When I press **ALT** key, every other time, it can response, I am not sure what happens, any help?

**UPDATE**
Later on, I find what wrong with this:
This is a specific case(when u hit ALT), the Chrome will use **ALT** as shortcut to toggle focus on its customize setting button:

[image]

That is why every other time, my key down can be responded.  **So, now the question becomes: How to bypass this?**

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Angular Material?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide No, just angular.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide I have update my question( find the reason), could you help this?

Comment: i'm not sure that i can yet) did you try to use any other key instead of alt? for example `k`, `l` or any other letter, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, do you have any `browser` constraint here and also can you update the `fiddle`.

```
<div ng-app>
  <h2>Example</h2>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
      <input ng-keydown="keypress($event)">
          <p>key: {{lastKey}}</p>
          <div ng-keydown="keypress($event)">
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
function myController($scope) {
  $scope.lastKey = "---"

  $scope.keypress = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 18){ // 'ALT' key
        //$scope.sidebarOpen = !$scope.sidebarOpen;
        $scope.lastKey = e.keyCode
    }
  };

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tyf64dp/

Comment: Thanks, could you try it on body tag? for Input, it works fine on my side too.

Comment: Sorry, it still not work on my side, to prove if every time it can respond, I change your code to `$scope.lastKey = $scope.lastKey+""+e.keyCode` And it turns out every other time, it can be triggered

Comment: I have update my question( find the reason), could you help this?

Comment: @Kuan: It works perfectly for me in chrome/firefox in ubuntu, even after u r change... btw its not going to settings icon as you mentioned in your post.... can you check the behavior in some other machine, if its the same.

Comment: Thanks for reply. From the UI, u can tell that I am using Windows, and all my machines are windows and behave same. But never mind, I just decide to change the Key